# C++ did wrong mathematics?

Tags: c++

I compiled this basic calculation in C++ but got wrong answers when did it on calculator. How is this possible even though i declared "ans" as "long long int"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;


int main(){

  long long int ans=1-1000000000+1-1000000000+1-1000000000;
  cout<<ans; //-2999999997
  return 0;
}
```

the expected answer is commented against `cout<<ans;`

but what compiler returned is: `1294967299`

please let me know where I went wrong in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more modern C++ compiler will tell you what the problem is, like mine did:

> warning: integer overflow in expression of type ‘int’ results in
>   ‘1294967299’

These numbers are too big for the default size of `int`s on your C++ implementation. You must tell your C++ compiler that your numbers are `long long`s:

```
long long int ans=1-1000000000LL+1-1000000000LL+1-1000000000LL;
```

All that `long long int` does is tell your C++ compiler that the ***result*** of the mathematical expression is a `long long int`. Your problem is that you must tell your C++ compiler that the numbers it uses to compute the expression are also `long long`s.

Answer (score 0):

It is taking `ints` and calculating them as `ints` and then storing the result in a `long long`. So an overflow happens before you store in `long long`

In order to do it right put `LL` at the end of each number.

Like this: `1LL` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You went wrong not enabling compiler warnings. Assuming you're using `g++` or `clang++`, use `-Wall` and you will be enlightened.